# How to I add extra elements to objects in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I have something like this :

```
  @bysParks = Array.new
  @nonBysParks = Array.new
  @bysMatch = Array.new
  @nonBysMatch = Array.new

  @parks = Park.find(:all,:conditions => ["name like ?" + queryString,parkname])
  @parks.each do |park|

  match = 5; #in reality this is some count * query

   if park.bys_park == true
     @bysParks << park
     @bysMatch << match
   else
     @nonBysParks << park
     @nonBysMatch << match
   end

  end #for each park
```

It would be desirable to include the match in the object or "struct" array, `@bysParks` and `@nonBysParks` so that I don't have to create parallel arrays like this.

Edit:  The goal is to avoid making `@bysMatch` and `@nonBysMatch` arrays, and include the information in the park object so that it can be passed with the BYSparks arrays.

Comment: Not clear, from what you've posted. I've only been doing ruby for a few months and I can see several ways you could iron this out. Hash and OpenStruct being two of them.

Comment: lol, this is week 3 with ruby for me.  I'll look into each of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but I believe you are saying you want to pull some parks and for each one you want to ideally assign a value to a property called `match` and store the result in an array?

So what you can do is just add an attribute to `Park`

```
class Park < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :match
end
```

Then your code above could be something like:

```
@parks = Park.find(:all,:conditions => ["name like ?" + queryString,parkname])
@parks.each do |park|
  match = 5 # or however you are getting match
  park.match = match # You can combine this with the line above.
  if park.bys_park
    @bysParks << park
  else
    @nonBysParks << park
  end
end
```

Even better though you can use nicer more compact ruby.

```
@parks = Park.find(:all,:conditions => ["name like ?" + queryString,parkname])
@parks.each {|p| p.match = 5}
@bysParks, @nonBysParks = @parks.partition {|p| p.bys_park}
```

What that does is grab all your parks, set the match attribute on each to 5, then partition the parks into two arrays based on whether the `bys_park` attribute on park is true.